# Map<Id, List<String>> or Map<Id, List<SObject>>, how access values?

Tags: map, collection, for

I need to have a `Map<Id, List<String>>` or a `Map<Id, List<Custom_Object__c>>` to store this data:

Id = Id of the record that is above, `List<String>`/`List<Custom_Object__c>` = Store an id and a type of the records below.

After that, I need to validate if the type is not xxx and store the id of bellow object, but I don't know how to do this in both ways, because:

- If I used the `List<String>` I would store in one index like this: `Id + ' - ' + Type` and I would need to check if `contains()`, the problem is that the check if is totally equal, and it would not be the case because has the id and type;
- And if I used the `List<Custom_Object__c>` I would just store the object and look the type field, but I don't know how to do this either, I tried access the type field after the `get()` but it said that doesn't exist this field.
  The only wrong solution that I could reach (I would like to avoid loop inside loop):

```java
for(Id objId : customObjectMap.keySet()){
     if(!(customObjectMap.get(objId).contains('XXXX') && customObjectMap.get(objId).contains('ZZZZ'))){
        //action to store the Id of the record bellow in a list
     }
}
```

Comment: What you want is a composite key. Unfortunately, you've simplified your question to the point where I can't write concrete code example(s). Consider making an [edit] to your question to be as reasonably detailed as possible.

Comment: Thanks! What I need to detail? Basic I wanna know which is the best approach and how to implemented, it could be a generic way only so I can understand the logic. The implement doubt it's for example, if the list of object is the best way and how can I see if the field type inside this list is equal to XXXX

Comment: I mean, it sounds like you want to create/map a child record given a parent id and a property on the child, correct? That can be serviced with a simple `Map<Custom_Object__c, Custom_Object__c>`, where the key is a composite key consisting of the parent Id and the type. You can easily find matching records using a composite key this way without `Id-Type` keys or such, which you said won't work for some reason... we're just trying to understand the logic behind what you're trying to do. See the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for more info.